# MATLAB: label prediction on new data using fitctree trained classifier

Tags: matlab, label, classification, decision-tree, predict

I built a simple classification tree with fitctree in MATLAB 2015b. I want to start using it to make predictions now on new data (tabletest). 'Predict' gives me an error and I'm unsure how to use kfoldPredict on new data.

code:

```
  predict(Mdl10feat,tabletest)
```

error:

```
Undefined function 'predict' for input arguments of type
'classreg.learning.partition.ClassificationPartitionedModel'.
```

Classifier:

```
Mdl10feat = 

  classreg.learning.partition.ClassificationPartitionedModel
    CrossValidatedModel: 'Tree'
         PredictorNames: {'fermin'  'MAJ'  'SOL'  'ECC'  'ORI'  'W'  'H'  'CIRC1'  'EQU'  'CONT'}
           ResponseName: 'classROI'
        NumObservations: 376810
                  KFold: 10
              Partition: [1x1 cvpartition]
             ClassNames: {'Hit'  'Miss'}
         ScoreTransform: 'none'
```

Input:

```
tabletest = 

    fermin     MAJ        SOL        ECC       ORI        W         H       CIRC1      EQU      CONT
    ______    ______    _______    _______    ______    ______    ______    ______    ______    ____

    29.748    46.342    0.98621    0.76677    87.506    27.307    43.691    1.0426    36.847    149
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`fitctree`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitctree.html), specifically for the [output argument `tree`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitctree.html#outputarg_tree), says the following:

> Classification tree, returned as a classification tree object.
>
> Using the `'CrossVal'`, `'KFold'`, `'Holdout'`, `'Leaveout'`, or `'CVPartition'` options results in a tree of class `ClassificationPartitionedModel`. **You cannot use a partitioned tree for prediction**, so this kind of tree does not have a `predict` method. Instead, use `kfoldPredict` to predict responses for observations not used for training.
>
> Otherwise, `tree` is of class `ClassificationTree`, and you can use the `predict` method to make predictions.

Since your output is of type [`ClassificationPartitionedModel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationpartitionedmodel-class.html), you therefore have to use the [`kfoldPredict`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationpartitionedmodel.kfoldpredict.html) method.

Note the statement I put in bold above: partitioned trees can't be used for prediction on new data. This is because the data set given to `fitctree` is used for *both* training and testing/validation. From your model output above, it shows that you are using a [`'KFold'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitctree.html#input_argument_namevalue_d119e317097) value of 10. This means that your data is first partitioned into 10 sets, then each one is used as a validation set for a model trained on the other 9. The `kfoldPredict` method gives you the results of the classification.

If you want to use all of the data to train the model, then use [`predict`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationtree.predict.html) on new data, you have to avoid using the `'CrossVal'`, `'KFold'`, `'Holdout'`, `'Leaveout'`, or `'CVPartition'` options when calling `fitctree`.

Comment: 2015b didn't seem to have kfoldPredict, had to download 2017b. I see how to check labels from the training data but I don't really see how to use this to get a class label for new data. How do I use kfoldPredict to get a label for the 'tabletest' example?